# Can you find the country of a mobile user based on ip ? (Rails 3.2/geocoder gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-geocoder

I need to customize website based on country of user. I want to use [geocoder gem](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder).

Can these type of tools and geocoder gem specifically find the country of a user using a mobile device (mobile phone, tablets...) ? or does it only work for set/fixed  computers/laptops ?

Note: in don't need something more precise than country identification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would work on mobile /tablets too and is not limited to a fixed set as you think.

[Reference](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#request-geocoding-by-ip-address)